# Argument Processing with python-click

Tags: python, python-3.x

A while back I wrote a simple python script to to change the elementary icon theme, [elm_icon](https://gist.github.com/rbtylee/225564776ef182e1084c3ee183232c9b), for [Bodhi Linux](https://www.bodhilinux.com/). In elm_icon, the argument processing is done by simply parsing sys.argv. I decided just for educational value to rewrite the argument parsing part of the script using various argument processing python modules, focusing mostly on some of the modules I have heard of for this task but never got around to using. The goal, of course, was to more or simulate the way the original script, elm_icon, functioned.

So when I got to trying to implement this with the python click module, it didn't seem so simple. But I admit I love the idea of argument parsing by simply adding a few decorators here and there to my code. But perhaps this program wasn't the best choice. It became rather difficult for me to achieve the desired functionality I wanted and I spent to much time closely going over the documentation, the code itself and various click related blogs and question/answers on the internet.

So here is the code I ended up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import click

__version__ = '0.1.0'
__license__ = 'WTFPLv2'

CONTEXT_SETTINGS = {'help_option_names': ['-h', '--help']}

'''
    elm_icon - set the elementary icon theme.

    This is test code to illustrate how to use click to implement the command
    line argument processing implemented in the current version of elm_icon.

    elm_icon
                with no options or arguments show current theme
    elm_icon THEME
                sets the elm theme to THEME if it exists
    elm_icon -- THEME
                sets the elm theme to THEME if it exists.
                for use with THEME names that look like options.
    elm_icon [OPTION]

    OPTIONS:
        -h, --help
                Show this help screen
        -a, --all
                List all available icon themes
        -v, --version
                Show program version
        -l, --license
                Show program license
    Any invalid arguments such as
            elm_icon -h -all
            elm_icon theme1 theme2
            elm_icon -h theme
            elm_icon -z   and so on
    should display a usage or help screen and an Error message
    and exit with return 1

    Invalid themes should also show an error message and exit with value 1

    Successful execution exits with return 0.
'''


# Seems overkill just to get the desired behavior ?
# Pieced together from Stackoverflow posts primarily by Stephen Rauch
# and studying the code for click
class CliGroup(click.Group):
    """
    Allow a default command for a group, customize parsing, and help/usage
    """

    def parse_args(self, ctx, args):
        def invalid(args):
            largs = len(args)
            # should simplify this Boolean expression
            #   or find a better way to determine this
            return largs > 2 or largs == 2 and args[0] != '--' \
                or largs == 1 and args[0] == '--'

        if invalid(args):
            ctx.fail('Invalid arguments or options')
        super(CliGroup, self).parse_args(ctx, args)

    def command(self, *args, **kwargs):
        default_command = kwargs.pop('default_command', False)
        if default_command and not args:
            kwargs['name'] = kwargs.get('name', '<>')
        decorator = super(
            CliGroup, self).command(*args, **kwargs)

        if default_command:
            def new_decorator(f):
                cmd = decorator(f)
                self.default_command = cmd.name
                return cmd

            return new_decorator

        return decorator

    def resolve_command(self, ctx, args):
        try:
            # test if the command parses
            return super(
                CliGroup, self).resolve_command(ctx, args)
        except click.UsageError:
            # command did not parse, assume it is the default command
            args.insert(0, self.default_command)
            return super(
                CliGroup, self).resolve_command(ctx, args)

    # is there a better way?
    def get_usage(self, ctx):
        formatter = ctx.make_formatter()
        self.format_usage(ctx, formatter)
        ret = formatter.getvalue().rstrip('\n')
        ret = ret.replace('COMMAND', '[THEME]').replace('[ARGS]...', '')
        return ret

    # both these seem very hackish
    def get_help(self, ctx):
        """Formats the help into a string and returns it.  This creates a
        formatter and will call into the following formatting methods:
        """

        ADD = "\n\nCommand:\n\n" \
              "If THEME is '_elm', the icon theme is set the icon theme" \
              " defined by the current elementary theme.\n\n" \
              "If no option or theme is specified, prints the current " \
              "elementary icon theme and exits."
        formatter = ctx.make_formatter()
        self.format_help(ctx, formatter)
        ret = formatter.getvalue()
        ret = ret.replace('COMMAND', '[THEME]').replace('[ARGS]...', '')
        return ret[:ret.index('Commands') - 2] + ADD


def show(ctx, param, value):
    if not value or ctx.resilient_parsing:
        return
    if param.human_readable_name == 'all':
        click.echo('Not implemented: list all themes')
    else:
        click.echo(__license__)
    ctx.exit()


@click.group(cls=CliGroup,  context_settings=CONTEXT_SETTINGS,
             invoke_without_command=True)
@click.pass_context
@click.option('-l', '--license', is_flag=True, callback=show,
              expose_value=False, is_eager=True,
              help='Show the license and exit')
@click.option('-a', '--all', is_flag=True, callback=show,
              expose_value=False, is_eager=True,
              help='List all elementary themes and exit')
@click.version_option(__version__, message='%(prog)s v%(version)s')
def cli(ctx):
    '''
    A simple cli script to set the icon theme elementary apps are using.
    This avoids the need to open elementary_config.
    '''
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        click.echo('Print current theme here')


@cli.command(default_command=True,
             context_settings={"ignore_unknown_options": True})
@click.argument('theme', nargs=1, type=click.Path(exists=False))
def set(theme):
    '''Set the elementary THEME and exit'''
    print('Not implemented: set themes here', theme)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

The question is am I going about this the right way? Is there any way to simplify or clarify this code?

Comment: There's not really a way to improve this code from a logic perspective. I can offer suggestions, but none that are meaningful in the way I think you are expecting...

Comment: @Zchpyvr, I really wasn't sure what to expect posting this here. Perhaps I missed some easier way to implement this user case in the click code or documents, after all I mostly skimmed them hunting for relevant parts. I am up for suggestions tho, I can see room for minor improvements such as the replacing my super comand with `super().parse_args(ctx, args)` or adding the missing doc strings. Anything else would be appreciated.